# Как правильно настроить .gitignore для Laravel

Tags: laravel, git, gitignore

Подскажите какие файлы и папки кроме ".env" должны быть в файле  .gitignore для разработки проекта на Laravel. Под разработкой я понимаю, что есть три экземпляра кода приложения: первый-основной на github, второй на локальной машине где я произвожу изменения и третий на хостинге. Если можно приведите примеры приложений, которые вы разрабатываете. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для генерации файлов `.gitignore` есть хороший сервис https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore.

Поддерживает большое количество языков, сред. Позволяет сделать комбинацию из нескольких шаблонов.

Можно просто скачать шаблоны из их репозитория на [GitHub](https://github.com/toptal/gitignore).